# Beamer: footer with current slide number but not total slide number; how to modify it?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using infolines as outer theme and I like it. I would like just to display the current slide number without the total slide number.

I find an answer provided by Gonzalo Medina as the following. It is very nice.

**However, how can I remove 0 from the left panel of footline as the following figure shown.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the "0" is not a "0" but it is an empty bracket. To remove it, either define an institute `\institute{where ever you want to be}` or use for example something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]